# Multiple servers in one directory

Tags: apache

Suppose I have a server at example.com

What if I wanted a different server at

```
example.com/server1
```

And a different one for

```
example.com/server2
```

Is this possible with apache?
Thanks - Vortex

Comment: what do you mean, "server"? apache **IS** a server, an http server. do you mean different **SITES**? yes, you can have different sites coexisting under the same domain in different directories.

Comment: @MarcB how can I do this?